How to move humanoid model charactor in unity with 3d coordinates from mediapipe pose estimation
I have a python program that runs mediapipe psoe estimation and sends 3D pose coordinates data via UDP to unity.
So far I've been able to render the pose results with spheres and lines.

Here is the sample coordinates of each body landmark after translating to unity coordinates.
[[-0.97, 11.58, -4.34], [-1.0, 11.87, -4.14], [-1.0, 11.88, -4.13], [-1.0, 11.88, -4.14], [-1.41, 11.81, -4.15], [-1.41, 11.81, -4.16], [-1.41, 11.82, -4.15], [-0.46, 11.92, -2.64], [-2.34, 11.65, -2.86], [-0.66, 11.46, -3.8], [-1.22, 11.37, -3.85], [1.19, 10.72, -1.23], [-3.12, 10.3, -2.47], [2.04, 9.17, -0.63], [-2.98, 8.71, -3.4], [3.43, 7.62, -1.72], [-0.01, 8.59, -5.06], [3.82, 7.15, -1.93], [1.07, 8.44, -5.46], [3.7, 7.07, -2.35], [1.22, 8.79, -5.46], [3.41, 7.48, -1.86], [0.33, 8.7, -5.08], [1.41, 7.27, 0.47], [-1.42, 7.13, -0.45], [0.99, 4.35, 2.16], [-1.27, 4.28, 0.96], [0.78, 1.9, 4.41], [-1.18, 1.94, 3.2], [0.89, 1.59, 4.51], [-1.15, 1.63, 3.3], [2.13, 1.21, 3.14], [-1.04, 1.1, 1.6]]


What I want is to move a humanoid character model in real-time with these coordinates.

Mediapipe or any pose estimation software gives output in form position in 3d space ,
you have to create coordinate origin at each point,
find angle between two adjacent points
convert to local space and apply rotation to relevant joint
"Cannot produce actual code here, Rough will be like above"
